# How do I get a Brother MFC 230c Printer working?

Tags: printing

After my connecting my Brother MFC 230c printer, Ubuntu searched for drivers and recommended Savin 230c driver. It installed. However, when I ask for a test print or if I try printing anything, my computer tells me that that the print job has been processed and completed. However, my printer is not printing anything physically. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/index.html

it tells you what to do and what to install

I suggest you remove your old printer installation before it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact thing happen to me withmy Brother HL-L2300D Series running on Ubuntu 19.04. It only printed when I clicked on "print test page" but nothing else.

I think this should work for most:
Follow the instructions given here:

https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl2700dw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625

In case the link is faulty in a few years, here is what it says:

"Step1. Download the tool.(linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz)

The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory.
(The directory location varies depending on your Linux distribution.)
e.g. /home/(LoginName)/Download"

To install the tool, just google "installing brother printer on linux download driver install tool".

"Step2. Open a terminal window.

Step3. Go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step. By using the cd command.

e.g. cd Downloads

Step4. Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

Command: gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz

e.g. gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz

Step5. Get superuser authorization with the "su" command or "sudo su" command.

Step6. Run the tool:

Command: bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* Brother machine name 
e.g. bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1 MFC-J880DW

Step7. The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.

When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",

For USB Users: Choose N(No)
 For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI number.

The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete."

You should be able to print now!

NOTICE: if it is still not printing, go to "system settings" and then "printers", where you will probably see two printers (but it's actually the same printer), pick the other as your default and get printing!